why aren't some vertices merging when merging by distance?
I keep trying to merge some vertices by distance. And even when they are super close, or even on top of each other, they don't merge. Why is this?


Use Merge at Centre if they're a little way apart.

I agree. But I need to figure out why merging by distance is not working because I'm working with over 1,000 points, and can't practically merge at center for all pairs individually.

increase merge distance or share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

I did this, but what I need to do is select all points and merge by a certain distance. Too large of a distance and it will mess up my object. The given distance on the link is more than enough (I measured the distance of the two points to be much less than the merge distance).

did u try uncheck "unselected"?
